# JavaScript window.scrollByLines() not working for url containing #(hash) id's

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html file like following.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Testing..</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function scrollLines(){
   window.scrollByLines(3);
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body onload="scrollLines()">
 <div id="1">1</div>
 <div id="2">2</div>
 <div id="3">3</div>
 <div id="4">4</div>
 <div id="5">5</div>
 <div id="6">6</div>
 <div id="7">7</div>
 <div id="8">8</div>
 <div id="9">9</div>
 <div id="10">10</div>
 <div id="11">11</div>
 <div id="12">12</div>
 <div id="13">13</div>
 <div id="14">14</div>
 <div id="15">15</div>
 <div id="16">16</div>
 <div id="17">17</div>
 <div id="18">18</div>
 <div id="19">19</div>
 <div id="20">20</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When opening html file in browser with #(hash) option like `http://localhost/test.html#7` I expect first line of display is `10` but I am getting `7`. But when opening html file without #(hash) I got first line as `3` as expected.

Why `scrollByLines(3);` doesn't work for #(hash) urls ?

Is there any other function/methods to do this ?

Comment: Because `#7` makes the page jumps to that to element, I think both events triggers at same time